# Python 3.* on Gentoo

Tags: python, gentoo

How to install python 3.* on Gentoo without compiling by hand?

Are there any ebuild or overlay  for this?

UPDATE:
now it's absolutely possible without any hacks

Comment: I love that server fault has become the go to place for these questions.  Far easier than asking on 4 different linux forums.

Comment: @sparks god forbid we go to distro ML/Forum and ask the people that actually know...

Comment: bizarre that this was closed as off-topic. This is the kind of server configuration problem that I would first think of searching here for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently in `python-experimental`, according to http://bugs.gentoo.org/250186

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.1 is now available on Gentoo in the unstable category.

Comment: I'd detoured to Arch for a while, and didn't see that Gentoo had an upgrade. *hug*

Guessing that I still need 2.* for Portage, though.

Comment: Yes, and most other things. In fact, installing 3.1 won't overwrite /usr/bin/python with the new version yet since so many things still need 2.X logic.